# Two phase processing: Do not output empty tags from phase-1 XSLT 2.0 processing

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I have some complex XSLT 2.0 transformations. I'm trying to find out if there is general purpose way to ensure that no empty tags are output. So... conceptually, a final stage of processing that recursively removes all empty tags. I understand this could be done by a separate XSLT that did nothing but filter out empty tags, but I need to have it all packaged together in a single one.

Comment: Excellent question (+1). See my answer for a detailed solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**This XSLT 2.0 transformation illustrates how multi-pass (in this case 2-pass) processing can be done**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*" mode="#all">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" mode="#current"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="/">
   <xsl:variable name="vPass1">
     <xsl:apply-templates/>
   </xsl:variable>

   <xsl:apply-templates select="$vPass1/*" mode="non-empty"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="text()[xs:integer(.) mod 2 eq 0]"/>

 <xsl:template match="*[not(node())]" mode="non-empty"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on this XML document**:

```
<nums>
  <num>01</num>
  <num>02</num>
  <num>03</num>
  <num>04</num>
  <num>05</num>
  <num>06</num>
  <num>07</num>
  <num>08</num>
  <num>09</num>
  <num>10</num>
</nums>
```

It creates a result document in the first pass (which is captured in the `$vPass1` variable), in which all `<num>` elements with contents even integer are stripped off their content and are empty. Then, in the second pass, applied in a specific mode, all empty elements are removed.

**The result of the transformation is**:

```
<nums>
   <num>01</num>
   <num>03</num>
   <num>05</num>
   <num>07</num>
   <num>09</num>
</nums>
```

**Do note the use of modes**, and the special modes `#all` and `#current`.

**Update:** The OP now wants in a comment to delete "recursively" "all nodes that have no non-empty descendant".

This can be implemented simpler using no explicit recursion. Just change:

```
 <xsl:template match="*[not(node())]" mode="non-empty"/>
```

to:

```
 <xsl:template match="*[not(descendant::text())]" mode="non-empty"/>
```

Comment: This answers the overall question, but there is a specific part it misses--recursively removing all empty tags... so I just need to change the "*[not(node())]" to an appropriate expression that means all nodes that have no non-empty descendant.

Comment: @taotree Next time state your question better. :) I think that it is best to make this new requirement a separate question -- it would be also an excellent question. You can use for the match pattern of the empty template this: `*[not(descendant::text())]`

Comment: @taotree Updated the answer to reflect your new requirement... :)