# Reapplying templates to output of other templates in XSLT

Tags: recursion, xslt-1.0

The following should be either simple or impossible to do, but right now I can not find out how, and so I ask. In my XSLT I have templates that produce elements, that then should again be transformed. More precise whenever a template outputs an element that in the original input would be subject to transformation it should again be transformed. Thereby infinite loops are possible but are to be avoided by careful design of the templates. Consider as an example:

input.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<example>
    <a />
    <b />
</example>
```

transform.xsl

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:transform version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()"><xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy></xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="a">a</xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="b">
        <B>b <a /></B>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

current-output.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<example>
    a
    <B>b <a/></B>
</example>
```

desired-output.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<example>
    a
    <B>b a</B>
</example>
```

What is the best solution to achieve this with just one transformation, if any?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the input from the other answers here is what I came up with to solve my problem. Consider as a more appropriate example input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<example>
    <a />
    <b />
    <c />
</example>
```

The elements `<a />`, `<b />` and `<c />` are used like `<replace />` in my original example, but as shown in the transformation, their templates each contain further references to them:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:transform version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:ext="http://exslt.org/common"
exclude-result-prefixes="ext">

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:variable name="this">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="normal" />
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="ext:node-set($this)" mode="normal" />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()" mode="normal">
        <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" /></xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="a" mode="normal">a</xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="b" mode="normal">
        <B>b <a /></B>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="c" mode="normal">
        <C>c <b /></C>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

When applied to the example input this transformation produces my wanted result of:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<example>
    a
    <B>b a</B>
    <C>c <B>b a</B></C>
</example>
```

Apparently all recursive references have been resolved. Although it is tested with some more complex examples, I am not sure whether or not it will work in all cases.

The idea behind this is the following: The first two templates are for copying. The one with `mode="normal"` is a plain identity transformation and the one without does the recursion. Modes are used in order to prevent an infinite loop within the recursion template.

Please let me know, what you think about this and whether there are obvious flaws in it!

Comment: hielsnoppe, You say: "Apparently all recursive references have been resolved. Although it is tested with some more complex examples, I am not sure whether or not it will work in all cases." This just shows that we don't have a well-defined problem (what are "all cases"?) so I don't think an answer like "yes, this is correct" would be correct. You are showing us a solution to a problem that you haven't defined and you are asking if this solution really solves the undefined problem.

Comment: I just refined my question and examples to better reflect my need. Thanks for urging me to precision.

Answer (score 2):

**This is a *two-pass* transformation that produces the wanted result**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:ext="http://exslt.org/common" exclude-result-prefixes="ext">

 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="@*|node()" name="identity">
   <xsl:copy>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
   </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:variable name="vrtfPass1">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:variable name="vPass1" select="ext:node-set($vrtfPass1)/*"/>

  <xsl:apply-templates select="$vPass1" mode="pass2"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="content">
   <wrapper>
     <replace />
     <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
   </wrapper>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="replace">
  <xsl:text>&#xA;Hello world&#xA;</xsl:text>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="@*|node()" mode="pass2">
  <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<example>
    <content>Lorem ipsum</content>
    <content><replace /></content>
</example>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<example>
   <wrapper>
Hello world
Lorem ipsum</wrapper>
   <wrapper>
Hello world

Hello world
</wrapper>
</example>
```

**Do note**:

In XSLT 1.0 the result of applying templates is of the infamous type RTF (Result Tree Fragment) and by definition it cannot be further accessed and processed, except using `xsl:copy-of` and the standard string functions.

This is why almost every XSLT 1.0 processor provides a vendor-specific extension function `xxx:node-set()` that takes an RTF and converts it to a "regular" tree whoce descendants can be accessed using any XPath expression. Here the `xxx` prefix must be bound to a vendor-specifix namespace-uri.

The EXSLT `ext:node-set()` is implemented by most XSLT processors -- thus its use guarantees significant degree of portability among different XSLT processors.

**For an additional multi-pass transformation example, see this**:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3200026/36305

**and this**:

http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect1/N169.html#d860e392

Comment: An interesting technique! But is there a way out, if I do not know in advance, how many passes will be necessary?

Comment: @hielsnoppe, Yes, and this is called *recursion*. Each step of the recursion produces the result from the current pass and passes it to the next pas.  Whenever your stop condition is met, the recursion will end.

Comment: Yes, I thought about using some kind of recursion, but could not figure out how at my current task. I will keep on trying, especially to find a proper stop condition, which would have to be some expression for "nothing has changed in the current pass".

Comment: I just found something that looks promising to me, based on your suggestion. It was great if you could tell me whether or not you think it is a good solution - see my answer below. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work in all cases, but there's a very simple way of achieving what you're asking. All you need to do is give your `replace` template a name, and call it with `xsl:call-template`. This only needs a couple of minor changes to your existing stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:transform version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()"><xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy></xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="content">
        <wrapper>
            <xsl:call-template name="replace"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </wrapper>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="replace" name="replace">
        Hello world
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

Comment: Yes, that is how I currently do things. The problem is, that my actual `<replace />` has some more data on it that would have to be passed to the called template as parameters. Not a problem for me, but parts of the code will have to be written by others who require as simple as possible syntax.