# Removing Duplicate Elements from my XML file by using an XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

Here is an example where I'd like to remove a duplicate entry if the ID is the same.  I'm pulling hits from system 'A' and system 'B'.  I want system 'A' to have precedence (i.e., if the ID is a duplicate, remove the element from system 'B').  Here's my example:

I am getting this result:

```
<HitList>
   <Hit System="A" ID="1"/>
   <Hit System="A" ID="2"/>
   <Hit System="A" ID="2"/>
   <Hit System="B" ID="1"/>
   <Hit System="B" ID="2"/>
   <Hit System="B" ID="3"/>
   <Hit System="B" ID="4"/>
</HitList>

I want this result (with the duplicates removed):

<HitList>
   <Hit System="A" ID="1"/>
   <Hit System="A" ID="2"/>
   <Hit System="B" ID="3"/>
   <Hit System="B" ID="4"/>
</HitList>
```

Current Code:

```
        <xsl:template match="/RetrievePersonSearchDataRequest">
                    <HitList>
                                <xsl:if test="string(RetrievePersonSearchDataRequest/SystemA/NamecheckResponse/@Status) = string(Succeeded)">
                                            <xsl:for-each select="SystemA/NamecheckResponse/BATCH/ITEMLIST/ITEM/VISQST/NCHITLIST/NCHIT">
                                                        <Hit>
                                                                    <xsl:attribute name="System"><xsl:text>A</xsl:text></xsl:attribute>
                                                                    <xsl:attribute name="PersonID"><xsl:value-of select="number(
                                                        REFUSAL/@UID)"/></xsl:attribute>
                                                        </Hit>
                                            </xsl:for-each>
                                </xsl:if>
                                <xsl:if test="string(RetrievePersonSearchDataRequest/SystemB/NamecheckResponse/@Status) = string(Succeeded)">
                                            <xsl:for-each select="SystemB/NamecheckResponse/PersonIDSearchResponse/personID">
                                                        <Hit>
                                                                    <xsl:attribute name="System"><xsl:text>B</xsl:text></xsl:attribute>
                                                                    <xsl:attribute name="PersonID"><xsl:value-of select="number(.)"/></xsl:attribute>
                                                        </Hit>
                                            </xsl:for-each>
                                </xsl:if>
                    </HitList>
        </xsl:template>
```

Comment: I am having trouble invoking any of the three proposed solutions.  I currently am checking a 'Status' attribute for System 'A' and populating all of the Hits.  Then, I am checking a different 'Status' attribute for System 'B' and populating all of the hits for this system.  Where should I invoke the template?  Should I use apply-templates or call-template?

Comment: I think that there is a misunderstanding here.  The HitList with the multiples above isn't my input.  My input XML has many layers and I'm grabbing the information from two separate places (in other words, two separate lists).  The HitList above is my current output and the HitList with four items is my desired output.  I will edit the question and show my XSLT that is producing the result above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Here is an efficient XSLT 1.0 solution using keys:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:key name="kHitById" match="Hit" use="@ID"/>
 <xsl:key name="kHitAById" match="Hit[@System = 'A']" use="@ID"/>

 <xsl:template match=
  "Hit[generate-id() = generate-id(key('kHitById',@ID)[1])]">

  <xsl:copy-of select=
  "key('kHitAById', @ID)[1]|current()[not(key('kHitAById', @ID))]"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the following XML document** (intentionally adapted from the provided one, to make it more interesting by placing some `B`s before the corresponding `A`s):

```
<HitList>
   <Hit System="B" ID="1"/>
   <Hit System="A" ID="1"/>
   <Hit System="B" ID="2"/>
   <Hit System="A" ID="2"/>
   <Hit System="A" ID="2"/>
   <Hit System="B" ID="3"/>
   <Hit System="B" ID="4"/>
</HitList>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
<Hit System="A" ID="1"/>
<Hit System="A" ID="2"/>
<Hit System="B" ID="3"/>
<Hit System="B" ID="4"/>
```

Comment: Whith java 7/groovy I get this cryptik exception : ERROR:  'Erreur lors de la vérification du type de l'expression 'filter-expr(funcall(current, []), [pred(funcall(not, [funcall(key, [literal-expr(kHitAById), step("attribute", 15)])]))])'.' Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException I can't even translate in english ! My feeling is current()[not(key('kHitAById', @ID))] doesn't work, I don't know why.

Comment: @Istao, Don't use incompliant/buggy XSLT processors. This solution works with any compliant XSLT processors -- on all eleven different XSLT processors I use daily on my computer: MSXML (3,4,6), Saxon (6.5.4 and 9.x), Altova (XMLSpy) for XSLT 1.0 and 2.0, XQSharp (XMLPrime).

Comment: @Dimitre - If a use this as a secondary transform, how can I retain the 'HitList' root element?

Comment: @jmac, Just add: `<xsl:template match="/*"><xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates/></xsl:copy></xsl:template>` .What do you mean by "secondary transform"?

Comment: @Dimitre - I answered my own question above concerning adding the root element back.  I do have another question.  I always want sytem 'A' results ahead of system 'B' results.  Your solution puts 'A' in front of 'B' when they start there and when there is a duplicate.  However, if 'B' has a unique ID and was ahead of 'A' to start, it will remain ahead of 'A'.  I am accepting your answer but was wondering your thoughts on this.

Comment: @iDmitre - I meant that I was already transforming an xml file to get the "duplicate" xml file.  So, this would be a "second" transformation to get my intended result.

Comment: @jmac, There are a lot of examples of "two-pass transformation" or of "multi-pass" transformation. You capture the result of the first transformation inside the body of an `xsl:variable` -- then you apply templates (usually in their own mode) on the result. In XSLT 1.0 one must first convert the RTF result into a regular tree by applying the `xxx:node-set()` function on it. Please, search SO for such quetions/answers. See for example this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3200026/36305

Answer (score 3):

This can be done with a single override of the identity template...

**XML Input**

```
<HitList>
    <Hit System="A" ID="1"/>
    <Hit System="A" ID="2"/>
    <Hit System="A" ID="2"/>
    <Hit System="B" ID="1"/>
    <Hit System="B" ID="2"/>
    <Hit System="B" ID="3"/>
    <Hit System="B" ID="4"/>
</HitList>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Hit[(@System='B' and @ID=../Hit[@System='A']/@ID) or 
        @ID = preceding-sibling::Hit[@System='A']/@ID]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<HitList>
   <Hit System="A" ID="1"/>
   <Hit System="A" ID="2"/>
   <Hit System="B" ID="3"/>
   <Hit System="B" ID="4"/>
</HitList>
```

Answer (score 3):

XSLT 2.0 solution:

```
<xsl:template match="HitList">
<HitList>
  <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-by="@ID">
    <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()[1]"/>
  </xsl:for-each-group>
</HitList>
</xsl:template>
```

This assumes the As will always precede the Bs. If that's not the case you could replace the inner instruction with

```
<xsl:copy-of select="(current-group()[@System='A'], current-group[@System='B'])[1]"/>
```