# Counting elements that are generated in XSLT1

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I'm trying to count the elements my transformation generates (must use XLST1). For example, my transformation creates:

```
<Parent>
  <ElementX Att1="2"/>
  <ElementY Att1="1"/>
  <ElementZ Att1="6"/>
</Parent>
```

I need to print 3 within the **same** transformation, because there are 3 child elements.

Can this be done?

Thanks.

Comment: And what does your transformation look like?

Comment: Please edit your post to include that whole template, and at least the template that calls that template.

Answer (score 0):

It would help a lot if you provide some extract of your XSLT.
I cn't give you a XSLT code without it. I'll try to give some "way" to the answer :

One solution could be to store the output into a nodeset (use the XSLT 1.0 extension which provides the nodeset() function) and apply the XPath count() function on this variable. After that just output your variable with xsl:value-of, and your count result the same way.

Answer (score 0):

**Here is a demo how to do this**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:ext="http://exslt.org/common" exclude-result-prefixes="ext">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:variable name="vrtfPass1">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:value-of select="count(ext:node-set($vrtfPass1)/*/*)"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
    <Parent>
      <ElementX Att1="2"/>
      <ElementY Att1="1"/>
      <ElementZ Att1="6"/>
    </Parent>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on any XML document (not used in this Demo), the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
3
```

**Explanation**:

A general way to process the result of the transformation (in a single transformation), is to organize it *in two passes* where we save the result of the first pass in a variable.

In the second pass we access the result and do the additional processing.

Do note that in XSLT 1.0 if the variable that captures the result of the first pass is of the infamous RTF (Result Tree Fragment) type and needs to be converted to a regular tree in order of any nodes inside this tree to be accessible (`xsl:copy-of` and `string()` are still allowed on an RTF).

This conversion to a regular tree is done by an extension function, which most often has the name `node-set` and always belongs to a vendor-defined namespace. In this demo we are using the `node-set()` extension function that belongs to the EXSLT namespace -- because most XSLT 1.0 processors implement EXSLT.

**For more information on multi-pass processing, see this**: [Two phase processing: Do not output empty tags from phase-1 XSLT 2.0 processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3199560/two-phase-processing-do-not-output-empty-tags-from-phase-1-xslt-2-0-processing)